# Prestashop 1.7 add link in product details that goes to contact form which is pre-compiled with the name of the product

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Good morning,

I'm using prestashop 1.7.2.4 and I would like to add a link in the pages of a product, that redirects the customer to the already existing contact form, which needs to be pre-compiled with the name of the selected product.

Do you know if there's a way to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your TPL :

```
{$link->getPageLink('contact')}?message='YOUR MESSAGE'
```

In html :

```
WEBSITE_URL?message='YOUR MESSAGE'
```

Regards

Comment: thanks, but after that, which command do i have to use to get the parameter? Normal $_GET['message'] doesn't seem to work

Comment: In your tpl product {$link->getPageLink('contact')}?message={$product.name}

Comment: that just prints the url, it doesnt get the parameter.

This is the link:  www.example.com/contact?message=CLOU%20COMPACT%20:%20STUFA%20A%20LEGNA.   

This is what gets printed with your command:  www.example.com/contact?message=

Comment: In product.tpl ?

Comment: sorry, i read wrong, in product.tpl i created the correct link, as you suggested, but i don't know to access the URL variable 'message' in contact.tpl, thanks

Comment: i think i understood how it works now, just testing a bit, thanks really much

Comment: i understand now, i didn't know that PS printed automatically the $message, so i was using a different variable named product, but now i got it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your link should be like this:

http://your-shop.com/contact-us?message=name_of_your_product

Comment: thanks, but after that, which command do i have to use to get the parameter?  Normal $_GET['message'] doesn't seem to work

Comment: i understand now, i didn't know that PS printed automatically the $message, so i was using a different variable named product, but now i got it, thanks